# PERL: Failed to cwd in FTP mode

Tags: perl, ftp, cd, cwd

I cannot cd to the path on remote machine in FTP mode. Please advise.

```
if (! $sftp->cwd($tgt)) {
    $error = $sftp->error;
    #print ("Unable to cd to $tgt: $error\n");
    print ("$error\n");
    logmsg("Unable to cd to $tgt: $error\n");
    mailmsg("Unable to cd to $tgt: $error\n");
   myExit();
} else {
    print ("Able to cd to $tgt: \n");
    logmsg("Able to cd to $tgt: \n");

}
```

The error I get is **0** only. I checked online, **0** means **syntax error** but I personally don't think so.

Comment: Which SFTP library are you using?  What is the value of `$tgt`?

Comment: my $sftp = Net::FTP->new($server, %args);

Comment: What is `$ftp->code()` and `$ftp->message()`?

Comment: Do not name your variable `sftp`, if you are using FTP. It's confusing.

Comment: `error` is a [`IO::Socket::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL) method. You should be looking at the return value of `message`